# Printing Hashes together CSV output RUBY

Tags: ruby, csv, file, hash

I'm learning Ruby and i need help with CSVs files.
I'm not finding the correct way to print output to a CSV file but i get recursivity and i don't want that.
Thats the code:

```
require "httparty"
require "csv"

class ConnexioEPPO
    include HTTParty
    base_uri 'https://data.eppo.int/api/rest/1.0'
    @@authtoken = "a9505d2ab257987580641d1a56de1f6c"

    def pests(eppocode)
        request = self.class.get("/taxon/#{eppocode}/pests?authtoken=#{@@authtoken}")
        result = request.parsed_response

        CSV.open("data.csv", "w", headers: result["Host"].first.keys) do |csv|
            result["Host"].each do |h|
                requestTax = self.class.get("/taxon/#{h["eppocode"]}/taxonomy?authtoken=#{@@authtoken}")
                resultTax = requestTax.parsed_response
                puts h["eppocode"]

                resultTax.each do |tax|
                    puts "#{tax["eppocode"]} #{tax["prefname"]}"
                    
                    planta = h.values << tax["eppocode"] +", "+ tax["prefname"]
                    csv << planta 
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

connexioEPPO = ConnexioEPPO.new
puts connexioEPPO.pests('1ULMG')
```

As you can see in the first part of the code im requesting (pests) a information as a Hash what contains(this is just few lines):

```
{"eppocode"=>"ANIDMA", "idclass"=>9, "labelclass"=>"Host", "fullname"=>"Anisandrus maiche"}
{"eppocode"=>"ANOLGL", "idclass"=>9, "labelclass"=>"Host", "fullname"=>"Anoplophora glabripennis"}
{"eppocode"=>"APRIGE", "idclass"=>9, "labelclass"=>"Host", "fullname"=>"Apriona germari"}
{"eppocode"=>"PHYPUL", "idclass"=>9, "labelclass"=>"Host", "fullname"=>"'Candidatus Phytoplasma ulmi'"}
```

And then I'm requesting (taxonomy) information again and what I'm doing is getting information where the field `eppocode` is equal to `eppocode` in the new requests (the idea is just get the taxonomy of the previously requested fields by `eppocode`)

And the idea is to get printed out in a CSV the first headers
`{"eppocode"=>"ANIDMA", "idclass"=>9, "labelclass"=>"Host", "fullname"=>"Anisandrus maiche"}`
and adding the taxonomy of the corresponding field

Wished output(example with one eppocode):

```
ANIDMA,9,Host,Anisandrus maiche,"1ANIMK, Animalia","1ARTHP, Arthropoda","1INSEC, Insecta","1COLEO, Coleoptera","1CURCF, Curculionidae","1SCOLS, Scolytinae","1ANIDG, Anisandrus","ANIDMA, Anisandrus maiche"
```

Actual output(example with one eppocode):

```
ANIDMA,9,Host,Anisandrus maiche,"1ANIMK, Animalia"
ANIDMA,9,Host,Anisandrus maiche,"1ARTHP, Arthropoda"
ANIDMA,9,Host,Anisandrus maiche,"1HEXAQ, Hexapoda"
ANIDMA,9,Host,Anisandrus maiche,"1INSEC, Insecta"
ANIDMA,9,Host,Anisandrus maiche,"1COLEO, Coleoptera"
ANIDMA,9,Host,Anisandrus maiche,"1CURCF, Curculionidae"
ANIDMA,9,Host,Anisandrus maiche,"1SCOLS, Scolytinae"
ANIDMA,9,Host,Anisandrus maiche,"1ANIDG, Anisandrus"
ANIDMA,9,Host,Anisandrus maiche,"ANIDMA, Anisandrus maiche"
```

And what I want is avoid that bunch of fields with the same information.
I hope you understand my questions
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that in order to fix your code with the minimal changes, you need to change the posting to the CSV to be outside of your `resultTax` loop, so something like the following might work?:

```
planta = h.values
resultTax.each do |tax|
  puts "#{tax["eppocode"]} #{tax["prefname"]}"
  planta << tax["eppocode"] +", "+ tax["prefname"]
end
csv << planta
```

Comment: Thanks for the help that worked for me!